# Grab Everything Except the Hyphen

Tags: regex

Using a regular expression I want to grab all text before the `-`. My below regex can successfully grab the text I want but it also grabs the hyphen. How can I stop this?

```
/(.*) -
```

For "abc - def" it returns "abc -" but I am attempting to get "abc ". I am performing this regex in Python.

Comment: print the group index 1. or use

Comment: Just reference the first group index to get only the captured result. What **language** are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is correct, you just need to print the group index 1. But it would print `abc` not `abc<space>`.

If you want to match the chars which exists before hyphen without the hyphen then you could  use positive lookahead.

```
.*?(?=-)
```

In python,

```
>>> import re
>>> re.match(r'(.*)-', "abc - def").group(1)
'abc '
>>> re.match(r'.*(?=-)', "abc - def").group()
'abc '
```

Comment: Why is lookahead even necessary?

Answer (score 3):

> I am performing this regex in Python.

As my comment stated above, reference the group index to grab the match result only.

```
>>> re.match('(.*)-', 'abc - def').group(1)
'abc '
```

But, I see no need to really use a regular expression here:

```
>>> 'abc - def'.split('-')[0]
'abc '
```

Answer (score 0):

All you want to do is grab everything up to the first - and store it into a group. Depending on the regex you are using (perl style or otherwise)

You would do something similar to what you have, but I would lazy look for the first match of the - and group everything before it.

That is to say:  (.*?)-
Would Return: "abc -"
But this would contain the group of "abc " and a group of the whole thing "abc -"
You merely want the group without the - and can access it by your language's group modifier.

https://regex101.com/r/cH6gO8/1

For python:

```
>>> re.match('(.*?)-', 'abc - cba').group(1)


In [1]: mystring = "abc - cba"                                                                                                                                                  

In [2]: import re                                                                                                                                                               

In [3]: re.match(r'(.*?)-', mystring).group(1)                                                                                                                                  
Out[3]: 'abc '
```

Answer (score 0):

Excluding the hyphen does not work for your?

`([^\-]) -*`